# Access Run time error - '-2147352567 (80020009)': subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've created a form where I can use a subform to load data from a query into textboxes so I can edit the data one at a time and update the database. This usually works fine except I have a run time error that randomly appears now and then - '-2147352567 (80020009)': The value you entered isn't valid for this field.'

If I stop running it and try running it again it usually works fine until the same run-time error appears. It's very inconsistent.

```
    Private Sub btn_SelectAgency_Click()

If Not (Me.qryAgencyWithoutMileagesub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.qryAgencyWithoutMileagesub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then

'get data to textbox control
    With Me.qryAgencyWithoutMileagesub.Form.Recordset
        Me.txt_AgencyID = .Fields("Agency ID")    
        Me.txt_AgencyName = .Fields("Agency Name")
        Me.txt_Address1 = .Fields("Address 1")
        Me.txt_Address2 = .Fields("Address 2")
        Me.txt_City = .Fields("City")
        Me.txt_Postcode = .Fields("Postcode")
        Me.txt_AgencyMileage = .Fields("Mileage")
        Me.txt_AgencyID.Tag = .Fields("Agency ID")

    End With
End If

Me.txt_AgencyMileage = ""

End Sub


Private Sub btn_Update_Click()

If Me.txt_AgencyMileage = "" Then
    MsgBox "No mileage added, add now"
    Cancel = True
Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE EstateAgent_tbl SET EstateAgent_AgentMileage = '" & Me.txt_AgencyMileage & "' where EstateAgent_AgentID=" & Me.txt_AgencyID.Tag
    Me.txt_AgencyID = ""
    Me.txt_AgencyName = ""
    Me.txt_Address1 = ""
    Me.txt_Address2 = ""
    Me.txt_City = ""
    Me.txt_Postcode = ""
    Me.txt_AgencyMileage = ""
End If

qryAgencyWithoutMileagesub.Form.Requery

    If Me.qryAgencyWithoutMileagesub.Form.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No agencies without mileage"
        DoCmd.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

The error is on this line

```
Me.txt_AgencyID = .Fields("Agency ID")
```

I would appreciate any help with this, thank you :)

Comment: Are you trying to add an ID number to an auto-gen ID number? i.e. agency ID when displaying vs addnew?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  it's loading an ID number already in the table into the textbox

Comment: Yes, but what if it is bound to a table, then that wont be possible when a new record.  Try putting `if not Me.NewRecord then `

Comment: I'm still getting the same run time error with that change

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset    
Set rs = Me.qryAgencyWithoutMileagesub.Form.RecordsetClone
    'get data to textbox control
With rs
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
        Me.txt_AgencyID = .Fields("Agency ID")    
        Me.txt_AgencyName = .Fields("Agency Name")
        Me.txt_Address1 = .Fields("Address 1")
        Me.txt_Address2 = .Fields("Address 2")
        Me.txt_City = .Fields("City")
        Me.txt_Postcode = .Fields("Postcode")
        Me.txt_AgencyMileage = .Fields("Mileage")
        Me.txt_AgencyID.Tag = .Fields("Agency ID")
    End If
End With

Set rs = Nothing


DoCmd.RefreshRecord 

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
```

'You can it try. That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude *Null* values:

```
If Not IsNull(.Fields("Agency ID").Value) Then        
    Me.txt_AgencyID.Value = .Fields("Agency ID").Value
End If
```

You may also try using the RecordsetClone:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.qryAgencyWithoutMileagesub.Form.RecordsetClone

        'get data to textbox control
    With rs
        If .RecordCount > 0 Then
            Me.txt_AgencyID = .Fields("Agency ID")    
            Me.txt_AgencyName = .Fields("Agency Name")
            Me.txt_Address1 = .Fields("Address 1")
            Me.txt_Address2 = .Fields("Address 2")
            Me.txt_City = .Fields("City")
            Me.txt_Postcode = .Fields("Postcode")
            Me.txt_AgencyMileage = .Fields("Mileage")
            Me.txt_AgencyID.Tag = .Fields("Agency ID")
        End If
    End With

Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks - that's got rid of the run time error, but I now get 'Run-Time error 3031 - no current record' instead occasionally, even though when I open the query, the record I'm trying to open from the subform is there with an Agency ID number

Comment: Thanks again - I've gone back to the old run time error :(. Is it not possible to stop error messages from appearing? For the old code I had, once I ended it and re-ran the script it would work without the runtime error appearing