# Weird "data has been changed" issue

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I'm experiencing a very weird issue with "data has been changed" errors.
I use ms access as a frontend and postgresql as backend. The backend used to be in ms access and there were no issues, then it was moved to sql server and there were no issues there either. The problem started when I moved to postgresql.

I have a table called Orders and a table called Job. Each order has multiple jobs, I have 2 forms, one parent form for the Order and one Subform for the Jobs (continuous form). I put the subform in a separate tab, first tab contains general order information and the second tab has the Job information. Job is connected Orders using a foreign key called OrderID, Id of Orders is equal to OrderID in Job.

Here is my problem:
I enter some information in the first tab, customer name, dates etc, then move to the second tab, do nothing in the second tab, go back to the first one and change a date. I get "The data has been changed" error

I'm confused as to why this is happening. Now why I call this weird?

First, if I put the subform on the first tab, I can change all fields of Orders just fine. IT's only if I put it on the second tab and, add some info, change tab, then go back and change an already existing value that I get the error

Second, if I make the subform on the second tab Unbound (so no ID - OrderID) connection, I get the SAME error

Third, the "usual" id for "The data has been changed" error is Runtime Error 440. But what I get is Runtime Error: "-2147352567 (80020009)". Searching online for this error didn't help because it can mean a lot of different things, including "The value you entered isn't valid for this field" like here:
[Access Run time error - '-2147352567 (80020009)': subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718872/access-run-time-error-2147352567-80020009-subform)
or many different results for code 80020009 but none for "the data has been changed"

MS access 2016, postgresql 12.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using ODBC to connect Access to Postgresql. If so do you  have timestamp fields in the data you working with? I have seen the above as the Postgres timestamp can have a higher precision then Access. This means when you go to `UPDATE` Access uses a truncated version of the timestamp and can't find the record and you get the error. For this and other possible causes see:

https://odbc.postgresql.org/faq.html#6.4

> 6. Microsoft Applications

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the comment, it put me on the right track, specifically that part about "higher precision". It appears that without using the "date" columns all works fine (I store the date of an order) now I need to figure out how to convert ms access "date" into postgresql "date". Probably has to do with regional format, access uses the format set in the Windows control Panel, but maybe Postgres uses a different one.

Comment: The issue is the precision. Postgres timestamps by default have a precision of microseconds. Access itself will only work to the nearest second. The quick solution is to make your Postgres timestamp fields `timestamp(0)` so the don't use fractional seconds. For a more in depth discussion see this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204135/how-to-insert-datetime-with-milliseconds-into-access-database#29205112)

Comment: Also, it really a `date` column or `datetime(timestamp)` one?

Comment: MS Access stores time as well as date data in a Date column but Postgres stores only Date, which is what caused the problem. I changed my Date columns in Postgres into "Timestamp with Time Zone" and the problem stopped, now Postgres stores the same data as access

Comment: Yeah, that would explain it.